# Advice on Evaluating $\frac{\sum _{n=1}^m(n \times\log_2(n))}{m \times\log_2(m)}$

Tags: summation

I recently came across this question:

Evaluate:
$$\frac{\sum _{n=1}^m(n \times\log_2(n))}{m \times\log_2(m)}$$
However, I'm not certain where to begin, I considered finding the bounds to the equation by integration, but I don't know if there's any way which is more specific than that.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: $\log_2(0)$ is undefined. Perhaps you want to sum from $n=1$.

Comment: Sorry, that's quite correct, I spend so much time working from 0 that I mistyped the question!

Comment: Look up change of base formula.

Comment: I would still end up with a sum of logs (from my memory or the base change formula) - it's that bit which I am really having the difficulty with.

Comment: Logs turn products into sums - so a sum of logs is a log of products.

Comment: Ah, that's true, I'll take a look into using that. I just had no idea where to start, and nothing was springing to mind! Thanks!

Comment: Ok... I end up with a product which I don't know how to evaluate, but I'll do a bit of research into that, thank you for your help!

Comment: And it seems as though the answer is $\log_{m^m}(\prod_{n=1}^m n^n)=\log_{m^m}(H(m))$, where $H(m)$ is the hyperfactorial function. Is there any way of closing a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sum of logs:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sum _{n=1}^m(n \times\log_2(n))}{m \times\log_2(m)}
&=\frac 1m\sum _{n=1}^m\frac{\log_2(n^n)}{\log_2(m)}\\
&=\frac 1m\sum _{n=1}^m\log_m(n^n)\\
&=\sum _{n=1}^m\log_m(n^{n/m})
\end{align}
As product:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sum _{n=1}^m(n \times\log_2(n))}{m \times\log_2(m)}
&=\frac 1m\sum _{n=1}^m\frac{\log_2(n^n)}{\log_2(m)}\\
&=\frac 1m\log_m\left(\prod_{n=1}^m n^n\right)\\
&=\log_m\sqrt[m]{\prod_{n=1}^m n^n}
\end{align}